# ¿cómo reiniciar app cerrando todos los activitys que estén en pila?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, activity

¿Cómo reiniciar app cerrando todos los `Activity`s que estén en pila? ¿O cerrar todos los `Activity`s abrir el main?(el main ya se encuentra en pila). Lo menciono ya que muchos `Activity`s llaman a otros por lo que se mantienen abiertas.

Como ya saben el `finish();` solo cierra el `Activity` actual y muestra el anterior que esta en pila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pude realizar con la siguiente

```
act.finishAffinity();
act.startActivity(new Intent(act, actMain.class));
```

con esto basta y me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que la aplicación vaya a la pantalla principal al pulsar el botón de "atrás, puedes sobrescribir el método `onBackPressed` de esta forma:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

De esta forma volverá al `MainActivity` sin tener nada en la pila, y si lo que quieres es cerrar la aplicación puedes llamar al `onBackPressed` con la siguiente línea de código:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Y así saldrá de la aplicación sin tener en cuenta lo que tiene almacenado en la pila.

Answer (score 0):

Existe una bandera que puedes pasar al Intent cuando vayas a una actividad. La siguiente acción quita de la pila las actividades previas almacenadas.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```